# Error 1064 - In statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to show the average price of products bought by customers from ‘Tucson’, however this query returns `null` even though there are two customers that have placed orders from Tuscon.

```
select AVG(product_price) from product where product_id in
(select product_id from orderline where order_id in
(select order_id from ordertable where cust_id in
(Select cust_id from customer where city = 'Tuscon')))
```

Comment: You'll note that `fom` is not `from`. Voting to close.

Comment: the updated question (about getting a null in the query) sounds like a data issue. Without seeing the data it would be very difficult for anyone to help. The query itself now looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

**`fom`** is not a recognized keyword. The MySQL parser doesn't know what to do with that, so it throws an error about "invalid syntax".

---

Consider using join operations in place of nested IN subqueries. If we are guaranteed:

- product_id is unique in product table
- order_id is unique in ordertable table
- cust_id is unique in customer table

then we can get an equivalent result set, the average of the price of distinct products that were ordered...

```
SELECT AVG(p.product_price)
  FROM ( SELECT l.product_id
           FROM orderline l
           JOIN ordertable o
             ON o.order_id = l.order_id
           JOIN customer c
             ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id
          WHERE c.city = 'Tuscon'
          GROUP BY l.product_id
       ) q
  JOIN product p
    ON p.product_id = l.product_id
```

If we want that "average price" of all products ordered (a different result,  with the average taking into account the number of times a product was ordered...then we could use a query like this:

```
SELECT AVG(p.product_price)
  FROM product p
  JOIN orderline l
    ON l.product_id = p.product_id
  JOIN ordertable o
    ON o.order_id = l.order_id
  JOIN customer c
    ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id
 WHERE c.city = 'Tuscon'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `fom` instead of `from` in your query: `select order_id fom ordertable where cust_id in`

This should be `select order_id from ordertable where cust_id in`